# Android: How to make my webview support language while loading a url?

Tags: java, android, webview

I'm trying to load url in a webview that contains telugu font. but it loads only boxes. i guess that android emulator browser does not support the font. How to make it support the url while loading in the webview? Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance...

Comment: Try setting with the text encoding in your device or do something in coading that encode the text.

Comment: Have you try with the "yourWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);"

Comment: Did u find the solution?

Comment: @nucleons : i tried with webview.loadWithBaseUrl(<syntax>), it worked for me bro.

Comment: @PattabiRaman is there any other setting i have to do for supporting indian language?

Comment: @Pritesh : try loadWithBaseUrl instead of loadUrl